# Retrieving id error from jQuery and PHP Chat

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, pdo

I have some problems on the retrieving id from php on mysql, somewhat, for what I found out, is that the id is saving somewhere (eg: something like a cache) where it saves it and create a loop when I don't ask for a loop.
For example[image: here in this image]

you can see the chat windows. Where it shows the user you are talking and the list of user which are online. (Like facebook)
The problem here is that when I toggle where it says "Nuno Monteiro" chat message. it hides it, and goes to the id "1" in this case but if I click on "Joane" and do that the id it will show as "1" and after "2".

And when I go back to "Nuno" I can not toggle and hide again but it gives me the id as "1" then "2" then "1" again "2" like that.
What I want is to pick just the current id from the function **callID(id)** and just select that one.
Here below you have the code:

**dashboard.php**:

```
<div class="chat-data" id="chat-data" style="display:none;">
                    <?php 

                        for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
                            if($result[$i]['online'] == 0) {
                                echo "<span onclick='callID(".$result[$i]['id'].");' class='user-btn".$result[$i]['id']."' style='padding: 7px; display:inline-block; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; cursor: pointer;'><span class='offline'></span> ".$result[$i]['firstname']." ".$result[$i]['lastname']."</span>";
                            } else {
                                echo "<span onclick='callID(".$result[$i]['id'].");' class='user-btn".$result[$i]['id']."' style='padding: 7px; display:inline-block; position: relative; border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc; width: 100%; cursor: pointer;'><span class='online'></span> ".$result[$i]['firstname']." ".$result[$i]['lastname']."</span>";
                            }
                        }

                    ?>
            </div>
```

This is the part from the chat(1) window.

The part of "Nuno Monteiro" window is also from **dashboard.php**, which is the following code:

```
<div class="chat-user" style="display: none;">
            <div class='user-title'>
                <span class="titles"></span>
                <span class='pull-right remove_field'>X</span>
            </div>
            <div class="chat-time">
                <div class="msg_data" id="msg_data">
                    <div class="friend_pic pull-left">
                        <img src="<?php echo $domain; ?>resources/img/babox_logo.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Nuno Monteiro" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="friend">
                        <span>Hey There are you ok?</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="your_pic pull-right">
                        <img src="<?php echo $domain; ?>resources/img/babox_logo.png" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="You" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="you">
                        <span>I am fine!</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="msg_box" id="msg_box">
                    <textarea id="chatbox"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

The **$domain** variable is where I get my website name so I don't need to change it in every code I have and change it only there.

That is picking up results from `$db = new DbManager();` and the variable **$result** will execute the select by doing: `$result = $db->execute_select($sql)`
The **$sql** variable is: `"SELECT * FROM users";` 
Then we going pass through our jQuery function (which I mention above):

```
function callID(id) {

    $(".chat-time").prop("id",id);  

    $(".chat-user").hide();
    $(".remove_field").click(function() {
        $(".chat-user").hide();
    });

    $.post('callID.php', {id : id }, function(rID) {
        // nothing on here
        $(".user-title").click(function(e) {
            $('#' + rID).toggle();
            e.preventDefault();
            alert(rID);
        });
        if(id == rID) {
            $(".chat-user").show();
            $(".user-title span.titles").html($(".user-btn" + rID).text());
        } else {
            $(".chat-user").hide();
        }
    });
}
```

this is part from my **general.js** script.

Then the script will go pick the information to the **callID.php**:

```
<?php

    include('application/database/dbmanager.php');

    $db = new DbManager();

    $sql = "SELECT id FROM users WHERE id='".$_POST['id']."'";
    $db->execute_select($sql);

    echo $_POST['id'];

?>
```

What I wanted to happen is that when I toggle in the online user chat on each username, go pick only the id of that user, so later I can save the messages in database and pick it up.

Comment: Your code is vulnerable to [**SQL injection attacks**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). You should use [**mysqli**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php) or [**PDO**](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) prepared statements with bound parameters as described in [**this post**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php).

Comment: @AlexHowansky this is a pdo config dbmanager class where it is on the dbmanager.php, and it has all the necessary functions there. If you want I can also update with the code of **dbmanager.php**

Comment: _"and it has all the necessary functions there"_ No it doesn't. You're building a SQL string by concatenating unfiltered user input. Once you pass `$sql` to the dbmanager, it's already too late.

Comment: So for what I saw in that post I have to use this: `$stmt = $pdo->prepare('SELECT * FROM employees WHERE name = :name');

$stmt->execute(array('name' => $name));

foreach ($stmt as $row) {
    // do something with $row
}` to my code be invulnerable right?

Comment: Something similar to that at least, yes...